# Start pointer not updating while passing by reference

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, stack

This is push function.

```
void push(struct node **head)
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp = new node;
    cout<<"enter the value";
    cin>>temp->data;
    temp->link=NULL;
    if(*head==NULL)
    {   
        *head=new node;
        *head=temp;
    }
    else{
        temp->link=*head;
        *head=temp;
}
}
```

this is how i am calling push.

```
struct node *start=NULL;
push(&start);
```

this is node

```
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *link;
};
```

now the problem: i don't think the list is updating. The start always remains the null. Don't know why.

edit:

```
void display(struct node **head)
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp=*head;
    if(*head==NULL){
        cout<<"\nthe head is NULL\n";
    }
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<temp->data;
        temp=temp->link;
    }

}

int main() {
    struct node *start=NULL;
    push(&start);
    push(&start);
    push(&start);
    push(&start);
    push(&start);
    display(&start);
    return 0; 
}
```

input:

1

2

3

4

5

now display out should have been 5 4 3 2 1 but there is some mistake.

Comment: If only there were a way to avoid that C abomination that is emulating pass-by-ref by using pointers. If only C++ had *true* references. That would be a feature worth considering, yes? :-)

Comment: Not your problem probably, but `*head=new node;` is superfluous.

Comment: A [mcve] would increase the likelihood and quality of answers.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ can you please explain why *head=new node; is superfluous?

Comment: @SamarYadav Because you assign `temp` in the next line anyways. The allocated memory is leaked.

Comment: Could not reproduce: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7663fe1a219ced89

Comment: @nwp please tell me where i am lacking in A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?

Comment: @SamarYadav See my link for a code that is closer to a mcve. Note the lack of user input that has no effect on outcome (more minimal than your code) and the fact that it compiles (includes and main) and could potentially therefore be verifiable. However, despite that, the example is not complete because it does not reproduce the problem that you describe.

Comment: It does not compile. When I copy/paste your code to for example http://ideone.com/ it should show the exact issue you are having, instead I have to include some headers and order the snippets correctly and write a main function and people are lazy and move on instead.

Comment: @user2079303 thanks but the problem is if i want to push another node. it does not connect with the older node. can you please try adding 5 nodes and displaying them.

Comment: @SamarYadav no. You do that, and show us how it goes wrong.

Comment: okay wait a min

Comment: @user2079303 i've added edit part just for the code you provided

Comment: if the code you posted is literally the same that you use, then try a clean rebuild. The code as you posted it should not result in an empty list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is mentioned by paxdiablo in the comments: C++ has pass by reference. Example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *link;
};

void push(node*& head)
{
    struct node *temp = new node;
    std::cout << "enter the value";
    std::cin >> temp->data;
    temp->link = head;
    head = temp;
}

int main()
{
    node *start = NULL;
    push(start);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative implementation:

```
void push(struct node** head_reference, int new_data)
{
    struct node* a_node = new node;
    a_node->data  = new_data;
    a_node->link = (*head_reference);    
    (*head_reference)    = a_node;
}

int main() {
    struct node* head = NULL;
    push(&head, 10);
    // rest of your code here
    return 0;
}
```